# Why I don't see the 2nd section title?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, hebrew, bidi

I update the packages at MikTex, and suddenly it's there is a problem with the fonts:
I'm using *LyX at WIN10 X64*.

MWE:

```
 % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}


\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\section{שלום}

שלום 
\begin{english}[variant=american]%
abcd
\end{english}%

\section{אבגד}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]
The title of the 2nd section `אבגד` - is missing....

Now, if I'm removing the English text:

```
  % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}


\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\section{שלום}

שלום 

\section{אבגד}
\end{document}
```

The output is fine:
[image]

Do you know why this happen and how can I solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: I copied your code with the problem and built it using XeLaTeX on Overleaf. It seems to work with no problem.

Comment: So where the problem might be? (I'm don't use Overleaf). Why for me it's not working?

Comment: (a) Is there any error messages from LyX? (b) Can you drop to the commandline (instead of using LyX) and run `xelatex` on your document and see if there are any error messages, and if the output is okay? // People on this site can only debug reproducible errors. As it stands the issue may be any of (i) differences between your MikTeX installation and the installed system on Overleaf (ii) interaction between LyX and xelatex (iii) internal issues with LyX (iv) something else. Try to provide as much info about your system as possible, maybe some Windows Lyx user can help reproduce.

Comment: @WillieWong - Here: https://file.io/7IOomdNLJivV - (I hope this is the log file)... And yes - I update MikTex before few hours....